# showing images from a tensorflow dataset class

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, image-processing, tensorflow2.0

Im trying to make a training set and a validation set from two folders. One with images of open hands and another with closed hands.
file structure is as follows: images->closed,open.
Im trying to use tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory which im not familiar with.
Im using python 3.7.4 and tf 2.3.1

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

path = './images'

dataset_train = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    path,
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="categorical",
    class_names=None,
    color_mode="grayscale",
    batch_size=32,
    image_size=(50, 50),
    shuffle=True,
    seed=123,
    validation_split=0.1,
    subset='training',
    interpolation="bilinear",
    follow_links=False,
)
dataset_test = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    path,
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="categorical",
    class_names=None,
    color_mode="grayscale",
    batch_size=32,
    image_size=(50, 50),
    shuffle=True,
    seed=123,
    validation_split=0.1,
    subset='validation',
    interpolation="bilinear",
    follow_links=False,
)
```

Im just testing out how it works with this code from [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class_names = dataset_train.class_names

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for images, labels in dataset_train.take(1):
  for i in range(9):
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
    plt.title(class_names[labels[i]])
    plt.axis("off")
```

When i test it i get this error: "TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index."
Tried to use

```
class_names=np.array(dataset_train.class_names)
```

But then i got this error: "IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices"

Also im not quite sure how the take(1) argument works in tf.

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced this error in a similar situation. For me it occurred on the line

```py
plt.title(class_names[labels[i]])
```

because we are using `label_mode="categorical"`, which returns one-hot encoded labels as a list of length equal to the number of classes.

Therefore, we cannot index into `class_names` with a list.